# how to implement custom widget in sencha?

Tags: sencha-touch, custom-component

I am planning to implement the custom widget in sencha as shown in the image.[image]

Does any body have any ideas on how to implement it? Any clues will be very helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Could you describe the widget you want because the picture is not really helpful here.

Answer (score -2):

Try look at ../resources/css/sencha_touch.css can you modified the class. I hope help you.

Comment: Modifying css files will definitely not help you creating that widget... Also, it is not good practice to change things n the sencha_touch.css. Using own CSS classes is much more appropriate.

Comment: What?? Do you know what is going on DOM elements in Sencha Touch? Sencha auto adjust whenever element on it. Please inspect the DOM for your knowledge before adding your comment please. What's going on...